# AS3 Automatically move object to another object when dragged

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

*EDIT: My problem seems at first a bit confusing. Look at this SWF, then you will surely understand my problem. http://www.fastswf.com/AL5D5ZA
Try to drag the green object (which is pDRA, the red one is pCOMPLETE) As you can see only pComplete moves, but the green box should be always in the same position as the red one when moved!*

I want to create a movable object using Action Script, but only some of the areas of the object should be dragged, so I have now the complete object movieclip (pCOMPLETE) and the object that can be dragged (pDRA)

*How can I make "pDRA" automatically move to "pCOMPLETE" when it has been dragged?*

Here is the script I already have:

```
pDRA.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag);

function fl_ClickToDrag(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    pCOMPLETE.startDrag();
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop);
function fl_ReleaseToDrop(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    pCOMPLETE.stopDrag();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place both your pDRA and pComplete in another movieClip so they would be dragged together and then drag that combined MovieClip.

Move your drag code to the timeline of that new movieclip (where both of your objects are in):

```
pDRA.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop);

function fl_ClickToDrag(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    this.startDrag();
}

function fl_ReleaseToDrop(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    this.stopDrag();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping and sorry for being unclear, however I used that code, but it was not what I was looking for

Comment: Ah now I get it after your edit, I have edited my answer :)